# Insert/update 50 records from JSON file into SQL table taking too much in ASP.NET Core MVC & EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am doing insert/update records from JSON file into a SQL table in the single action method. I am inserting only 50 records but it takes too much time. I am new to ASP.NET Core MVC. Don't know whether my too much for each loop creates the issue or my database logic. Please can anybody help me to correct this issue?

I am reading json and based on custom mapping, I am doing insert or update to table column from json object values.

Please look at my code here:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult InsertProductDetails()
{
    int getcountProductName = (from gcPN in _context.K360MappingMasters
                               where gcPN.K360Catalog == "Name" && gcPN.ApiContent == baseurl
                               select gcPN).Count();

    if (getcountProductName == 0)
    {
        return Json(new { Status = "error", Message = "Required ProductName catalog not yet mapped , unable to insert productdetails" });
    }
    else if (getcountProductName == 1)
    {
        try
        {
            using WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            string contentString = wc.DownloadString(baseurl);

            List<Dictionary<string, string>> ListJsonProductContent = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
            List<string> ListProductsCheck = new List<string>();

            var token = JToken.Parse(contentString);

            if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)  // "["
            {
                ListJsonProductContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(contentString);
            }
            else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object) // "{"
            {
                var ObjectResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(contentString);

                foreach (var x in ObjectResponse)
                {
                    string key = x.Key.ToString();
                    string val = x.Value.ToString();

                    foreach (var dicItemML in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(val))
                    {
                        ListJsonProductContent.Add(dicItemML);
                    }
                }
            }

            List<K360MappingMaster> ListMappedDataDb = new List<K360MappingMaster>();
            var VLinqQuery = from KMM in _context.K360MappingMasters
                             where KMM.ApiContent != null && KMM.ApiContent == baseurl
                             select KMM;

            ListMappedDataDb = VLinqQuery.ToList();

            foreach (var dicItemML in ListJsonProductContent)
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> updItem = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                foreach (var itemMl in dicItemML)
                {
                    var catalogProductsCheck = _context.CatalogProducts.ToList();
                    var result = catalogProductsCheck.Select(s => s.Name).ToList().Contains(itemMl.Value);

                    if (result == true)
                        ListProductsCheck.Add(itemMl.Value.ToString());

                    if (ListMappedDataDb.Select(s => s.ApiCatalog).ToList().Contains(itemMl.Key))
                    {
                        foreach (K360MappingMaster data in ListMappedDataDb.Where(s => s.ApiCatalog == itemMl.Key))
                        {
                            if (updItem.ContainsKey(data.K360Catalog))
                            {
                                if (data.K360Catalog == "Specification")
                                {
                                    updItem[data.K360Catalog] += "<p>" + itemMl.Key + " :" + itemMl.Value + "<p>";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    updItem[data.K360Catalog] += " " + itemMl.Value;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (data.K360Catalog == "Specification")
                                {
                                    updItem.Add(data.K360Catalog, "<p>" + itemMl.Key + " :" + itemMl.Value + "<p>");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    updItem.Add(data.K360Catalog, itemMl.Value);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    dicItemML.Remove(itemMl.Key);
                }

                foreach (var itemM2 in updItem)
                {
                    dicItemML.Add(itemM2.Key, itemM2.Value);
                }
            }

            List<CatalogProduct> ListKp = new List<CatalogProduct>();

            foreach (var dicItem in ListJsonProductContent)
            {
                CatalogProduct Ctgkp = new CatalogProduct
                    {
                        Name = dicItem.ContainsKey("Name") ? dicItem["Name"] : "No Product",
                        Slug = dicItem.ContainsKey("Name") ? string.Concat(dicItem["Name"].Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c))).ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) : "No Slug",
                        Price = dicItem.ContainsKey("Price") ? decimal.Parse(dicItem["Price"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : default,
                        ShortDescription = dicItem.ContainsKey("ShortDescription") ? dicItem["ShortDescription"] : null,
                        Description = dicItem.ContainsKey("Description") ? dicItem["Description"] : null,
                        Specification = dicItem.ContainsKey("Specification") ? dicItem["Specification"] : null,
                        RatingAverage = dicItem.ContainsKey("RatingAverage") ? double.Parse(dicItem["RatingAverage"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : null,
                        MetaTitle = dicItem.ContainsKey("MetaTitle") ? dicItem["MetaTitle"] : null,
                        MetaKeywords = dicItem.ContainsKey("MetaKeywords") ? dicItem["MetaKeywords"] : null,
                        MetaDescription = dicItem.ContainsKey("MetaDescription") ? dicItem["MetaDescription"] : null,
                        Sku = dicItem.ContainsKey("Sku") ? dicItem["Sku"] : null,
                        Gtin = dicItem.ContainsKey("Gtin") ? dicItem["Gtin"] : null,
                        NormalizedName = dicItem.ContainsKey("NormalizedName") ? dicItem["NormalizedName"] : null,
                        StockQuantity = dicItem.ContainsKey("StockQuantity") ? int.Parse(dicItem["StockQuantity"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : 50,
                        ReviewsCount = dicItem.ContainsKey("ReviewsCount") ? int.Parse(dicItem["ReviewsCount"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : default,
                        DisplayOrder = dicItem.ContainsKey("DisplayOrder") ? int.Parse(dicItem["DisplayOrder"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : 1,
                        OldPrice = dicItem.ContainsKey("OldPrice") ? decimal.Parse(dicItem["OldPrice"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : null,
                        SpecialPrice = dicItem.ContainsKey("SpecialPrice") ? decimal.Parse(dicItem["SpecialPrice"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : null,
                        SpecialPriceStart = dicItem.ContainsKey("SpecialPriceStart") ? DateTimeOffset.Parse(dicItem["SpecialPriceStart"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : null,
                        SpecialPriceEnd = dicItem.ContainsKey("SpecialPriceEnd") ? DateTimeOffset.Parse(dicItem["SpecialPriceEnd"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : null,
                        IsPublished = true,
                        PublishedOn = DateTimeOffset.Now,
                        CreatedById = 10,
                        IsDeleted = false,
                        CreatedOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                        LatestUpdatedOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                        LatestUpdatedById = 10,
                        HasOptions = false,
                        IsVisibleIndividually = true,
                        IsFeatured = true,
                        IsCallForPricing = false,
                        IsAllowToOrder = true,
                        StockTrackingIsEnabled = true
                    };
                    ListKp.Add(Ctgkp);
                }                   

                using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int numCpTotal = 0;                           
                        var catalogProducts = _context.CatalogProducts.ToList();
                        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<CatalogProduct, CatalogProduct>()
                                    .ForMember(c => c.Id, opt => opt.Ignore()));
                        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

                        _context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

                        foreach (var kp in ListKp)
                        {
                            var existingRootProduct = _context.CatalogProducts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == kp.Name);
                            if (existingRootProduct == null)
                            {
                                if (ListProductsCheck.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    var firstItem = ListProductsCheck.ToList();
                                    foreach (var item in firstItem)
                                    {
                                        _context.CatalogProducts.RemoveRange(_context.CatalogProducts.Where(c => c.Name == item));
                                       
                                        _context.CoreEntities.RemoveRange(_context.CoreEntities.Where(c => c.Name == item));
                                        _context.SaveChanges();
                                    }
                                }
                                _context.CatalogProducts.Add(kp);
                                _context.SaveChanges(); 

                               
                                CoreEntity ce = new CoreEntity
                                {
                                    Name = kp.Name,
                                    Slug = string.Concat(kp.Name.Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c))).ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                                    EntityId = kp.Id,
                                    EntityTypeId = "Product",
                                };                                   
                                _context.CoreEntities.Add(ce);
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                mapper.Map<CatalogProduct, CatalogProduct>(kp, existingRootProduct);
                                
                            }
                        }

                              (from q in _context.K360MappingMasters
                               where q.ApiContent == baseurl
                               select q).ToList().ForEach(x => x.InsertStatusFlag = true);

                        _context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
                        numCpTotal = _context.SaveChanges();
                        _context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true; 
                        transaction.Commit();
                        return Json(new { Status = "success", Message = "No conflicts. " + numCpTotal + " product details saved." });
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        return Json(new { Status = "warning", Message = ex.Message });
                        throw new Exception();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { Status = "warning", Message = ex.Message });
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
}
```